# Alternative Access Mappings and Catalog Item Friendly URLs

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping, cross-site-publishing, catalog

I have created two site collections - a product catalog site collection and a publishing site collection. On the product catalog site I have created a new list and linked it into the publishing site as a catalog.

There are a number of alternate access mappings set up on the web application for intranet usage and public internet usage. The search service application uses the intranet address for crawling.

Whenever I browse the site via the intranet address, the term driven navigation / friendly urls of the catalog items works successfully. The urls are set to:

> [site url]/metadata terms/list item title

However, when I browse the site via the internet address the url of the catalog items are set to the explicit url of the list item in the product catalog site:

> [site url]/sites/[product catalog site name]/lists/[list name]...

Is this a known limitation of cross site publishing / sharepoint catalogs or is there a way to have the catalog work using friendly urls for both access mappings?

Comment: Am having the same issue. I'd be really interested to know if you ended up figuring this out...

Comment: @dcarson2, unfortunately I have yet to find a solution that allows friendly urls on multiple access mappings.

Comment: I believe this (annoyingly) is a product limitation. I did see it in either MSDN or TechNet documentation at some point (don't have the link to hand).